# Can't connect to ubuntu 22.04 hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot, ap-hotspot, wifi-direct

wifi hotspot is created easily and is visible to other devices too. but on the other hand after typing password to connect it just do nothing. can't able to connect my ubuntu 22.04 created hotspot can anyone help me with this ? By default hotspot configuration is WEP security which also can't be modified using nm-connection-editor. i have already tried this.

Comment: ufw enabled? Yesterday I tried Ubuntu Mate 22 and may for sure say that nm is not adding necessary rules, therefore, with running ufw it is not possible to connect.

Comment: @Andra I have got the same issue, and ufw is inactived.

Answer (score 13):

This is the only solution worked with me, by downgrading `wpa_supplicant-2.10` to `wpa_supplicant-2.9`:

**Step 1: Add the required repository for downgrading**

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following “old-releases” repository to the end of the file.

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

And don’t forget to save it.

**Step 2: Downgrade wpa_supplicant**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt --allow-downgrades install wpasupplicant=2:2.9.0-21build1
```

Then use the Network-Manager UI to create new HOTSPOT

[source](https://blog.incompetent.me/2023/02/ubuntu-2204-hotspot-stops-working.html)

Comment: This did the trick. Nothing else was needed.

Comment: Thanks!!! Just one repo is required for this: `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main`, the package there is `wpasupplicant=2:2.9-1ubuntu4`

Comment: Finally lock the version with `sudo apt-mark hold wpasupplicant`

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 10):

#### BE CAREFUL WITH THE FIREWALL

First try:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

If that solves the problem, you can do:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw       allow in  on wlo1
sudo ufw route allow out on enp41s0
```

My system works with:

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
[ 1] Anywhere on wlo1           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] Anywhere on enp41s0        ALLOW FWD   Anywhere       (out)
[ 3] Anywhere (v6) on wlo1      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 4] Anywhere (v6) on enp41s0   ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)  (out)
```

Only `[ 1]` and `[ 2]` are strictly necessary.

#----------------------------------------------------- On my system:

With WiFi on:

```
ifconfig

> enp41s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.2.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
>         inet6 fe80::19b0:6542:ee4:5982  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 00:d8:61:9e:2b:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 46282  bytes 39478576 (39.4 MB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 38257  bytes 7380268 (7.3 MB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> enp42s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         ether 00:d8:61:9e:2b:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 1981  bytes 318831 (318.8 KB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 1981  bytes 318831 (318.8 KB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.2.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
>         inet6 fe80::1c39:c0d6:43bd:fcf0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 38:00:25:95:18:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 50  bytes 17772 (17.7 KB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 48  bytes 7067 (7.0 KB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

This means that the WiFi hotspot:
input is from wlo1
Output is to enp42s0
```

**Edit (June 03, 2023):**

For those who haven't yet figured out how to identify the input and output, here is the right way: ufw stores its logs in this location: `/var/log/ufw.log`

So you can enable the firewall and start monitoring updates from ufw using this command in a new terminal:

`tail -f /var/log/ufw.log`

Now when you connect to hotspot and attempt to view some webpage, and if the request gets blocked by ufw, you will find a line like this in the terminal (sample line from my system):

`Jun  3 09:44:04: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT=ppp0 MAC=ac:12:03:69:63:6a:16:5...`

This indicates that the IN is `wlo1` and OUT is `ppp0`. You should be able to use the method above to whitelist this path and the hotspot will start working as expected.

Comment: `sudo ufw disable` work like a charm, but `ufw allow` didn't work for me. Mine is input from wlp0s20f3 and output to enp1s0

Comment: `sudo ufw disable` alone solved this problem. This might be a noob question but why should I follow other steps if the disabling command fixes the hotspot issue?

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me. I was stuck finding input and output, and later realized that it is available in `/var/log/ufw.log`. For those who haven't figured it out yet, you will find a line like `[UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT=ppp0` in the ufw.log file, which will tell you the in and out you need to configure

Comment: `sudo ufw route allow out on <IF_LAN>` fixed my issues, *UFW* will create a FWD `forward' rule to enable traffic forwarding from Wifi to Ethernet. thanks a lot.

Comment: first and second instructions solved mine. ive been pulling my hair for days. thank you very much! `[+1]`

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem.
If it's any use, I got it working but without security.

Turn off the wifi, via the drop down top menu. Then go to:
Show Applications --> Advanced Network

Then in "Network Connections" dialog:

1. Remove the Hotspot connection
2. Add a new one (+ sign)
3. choose WIFI for type of connection
4. Name it and give it a SSID
5. Change MODE to Hotspot
6. Save
   Then restart the wifi via the top menu, and try to connect with your phone.

I didn't mess much with a passwords as I don't need them.

Comment: This worked for Android 11. But, after my mobile auto-upgraded to Android 12, this isn't working any longer :(  Is there any other possible solution ?

Comment: This is still an issue now it’s my problem trying to use hotspot with kde on Ubuntu and yeah works fine no password. I will try the package downgrade hack/patch thanks

Answer (score 1):

A better solution than downgrading can be found [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/104).  Apparently, Protected Management Frames have to be disabled.

- Create the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/99-my.conf` with content:

  ```
  [connection]
  wifi-sec.pmf=1
  ```
- Restart NetworkManager:

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
  ```

Comment: Disabling uwf worked for me. Downgrading `wpa_supplicant` or disabling `Protected Management Frames` as you describe did not work for me.

Comment: This one worked for me! Ubuntu 22.04 upgraded from 20.04, standard install

Answer (score 0):

I needed both the answers from GNassro and Mario Galinda to get a working workaround. So you need to configure the firewall AND you need to downgrade the wpasupplicant package. If I do only the firewall thing, the connection still drops after a while.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the mentioned solutions, but none of them worked with security.

But as mentioned by Farmer-G, I was able to get it working without security. So I tried changing the security from there, to my surprise it worked with WEP security. If you don't have it working with this, try changing the security method, you may have others security types that work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had configures trough "nm-connection-editor" that when connecting to the particular Wi-Fi hotspot it would connect to VPN automatically. For some reason after updating from 20.04 to 22.04 imported VPN profiles did not work and resulted with Wi-Fi automatically disconnecting with "Connection failed" message. After reimporting .ovpn profile it worked all the same.

Answer (score -1):

Seems there are issues with firewall.

For me it's worked:

1. Turn off wifi.
2. Be sure that firewall disabled.

   ```
    $ sudo ufw enable
    $ sudo ufw disable
   ```
3. Turn on wifi and hotspot.

Comment: yeah, firewall issues are at least part of the problem, but turning it off is a dangerous solution

Comment: @Maarten do you have any detailed solution? Could you share it with me, please?

Comment: Well look at my answer to this question, that's what worked for me