# Ubuntu 22.04 limit who can connect to my hotspot/ set it to connect to a particular device only and invisible to others

Tags: networking, wireless, bug-reporting, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

Since there is a bug in the recent ubuntu 22.04 which prevents my phone to connect to the hotspot when the hotspot is created using WPA3 security.
Found in an online forum that creating the hotspot without any security makes it able to connect ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406149/cant-connect-to-ubuntu-22-04-hotspot)), but now many people are connecting to my hotspot which I don't want.
Anyone else facing this hotspot issue in 22.04? 
And possible solution? Either of fixing the hotspot issue or limiting users to my network would be fine.

Comment: Why does the inability to use WPA3 mean you can't use any security? Why can't you use WPA2?

Comment: Same situation with WPA2

Comment: Set WPA2 security with a new SSID and try again.