# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS - Hotspot - Connected but without internet on Android 11

Tags: internet, 22.04, connection, hot-spot

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, the hotspot didn't work correctly anymore. It worked well on version 20.04.
I have tried some solutions like removing the old Hotspot and creating a new one without WPA security but none worked ([Can't connect to ubuntu 22.04 hotspot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406149/cant-connect-to-ubuntu-22-04-hotspot)).
I have seen this bug report but seems no solution or work in progress on this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1971538).

It will realy help if you have any solution for this. Thanks

Comment: downgrade wpasupplicant to v2.9 Look this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406149/cant-connect-to-ubuntu-22-04-hotspot

Comment: @jordi I have tried it, but unfortunatly not working for me. The related source : https://blog.incompetent.me/2022/07/27/workaround-ubuntu-22-04-hotspot-stops-working/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now I am able to connect correctly from android device on the hotpost created on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. More probably by updating the system frequently but additionally by trying to disable firewall too with:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

I don't actualy know the main reason but it worked and I hope it can help.
For more information about steps to enable/disable firewall, check here:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-firewall-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-linux

Comment: Disabling firewall worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Add the required repository for downgrading**

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**Add the following “old-releases” repository to the end of the file.**

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

**Step 2: Downgrade wpa_supplicant**

Run the following to fetch your package list and downgrade the package

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt --allow-downgrades install wpasupplicant=2:2.9.0-21build1 Do make
```

sure you have marked the package to prevent any update for now.

```
sudo apt-mark hold wpasupplicant
```

**Step 3: Setup Hotspot**

You can use use the Network-Manager UI or just run the following command to start or create a hotspot. Since I am on using the XFCE desktop environment, it is pretty much easier to use command-line.

```
nmcli dev wifi hotspot
```

You can view the password via the the Network-Manager UI or you can always view it with the following command

```
nmcli dev wifi show-password
```

**Step 4: Connecting to hotspot**

If all thing goes well, you should now be able to connect to your Ubuntu (22.04) WiFi hotspot with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not very scientific, but it started working for me when I tried pinging my Ubuntu IP address (not 10.42.0.1, but the "WAN" side of the Hotspot) from the Android device (via ADB over USB).

I launched the ping command first, then retried the connection while the ping was still running/failing, then it succeeded:

```
$ adb shell ping 192.168.1.123
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
PING 192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=1.94 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=48.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=9.48 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=112 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=12.2 ms
```

Prior to this, I had tried downgrading wpa_supplicant + reboot, then went back to 2.10 (mark unhold + update + upgrade + reboot). Just mentioning it in case it contributed to the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and to me helped this.

Click show applications, then utilities, then advanced network configuration. Double click on Hotspot. Click table General and make sure there is tick on Connect automatically with priority and set value -999. Then save and restart.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (note that the english wording might be slightly different):

**Open the "Advanced Network Settings" Application.**

**Select your Hotspot Connection and double-click to open the configuration.**

**Go to the "general" tab and uncheck "All users may use this network"**

**Save the settings.**

Then, Internet worked immediately over Hotspot.

I think this has do to with security/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have an android version 11 below I will describe how I solved the problem:

Steps:

- Go into settings on your android 11 cell phone,
- Under internet and networks: set the hotspot security password to "none"

and that's it in my case. It worked right away...