# ubuntu 22.04 wifi hotspot not sharing internet but is assigning ip addresses

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet, ap-hotspot

So the title says it all  really.  Wifi hotspot is set up, I can see it with my phone, can connect and get assigned an IP address but the phone has no internet connection.

It seems there is a problem with Ubuntu 22.04 completing the sharing part, maybe it needs a bridge between the wifi and ethernet?

the ubuntu machine has a static ip but the home router is serving IP address to the rest of the network in the 192.168.88.* range, ubuntu's hotspot setup is assigning ips in the 10.42.0.* range

I have spent about 6 hours on google trying various things with no luck. How do I get the last step setup so the devices connected to my wifi can share the network adn get access to the internet from the PC's wired ethernet connection?

Comment: this error was reported
[as a bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1971538)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS - Hotspot - Connected but without internet on Android 11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425382/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-hotspot-connected-but-without-internet-on-android-11)